# Overriding windows menu

Tags: c#, menu

I am in need of blocking windows menu: when I press the windows button in keyboard, I don't want any actions to be performed, how should I do programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually a registry hack. Please read the [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216893) from MS. You can try adding the registry key through your program.

Or simply remove the key from the keyboard.

Edit: Took 5 secs to search for your answer in Google. It's less than the time taken for you to type the question.

Comment: Please read the question "how should i do programatically"
Now, what's so programmatic about the solution?

Comment: Sorry I dont feel like spoon feeding anyone. I have given enough clue to find the "programatic" answer.

Comment: He told him to add a registry key via his program. That *is* an answer. This site is about helping people but not doing the work for them. Voted up.